# Targus USB number pad not working in Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian, usb, keyboard

I am running a fresh install of Wheezy x86 and trying to connect a Targus number pad (model AKP10US) which has the USB Vendor/Model IDs of 05A4 / 9840.  (FWIW the system is also running in VirtualBox)

However the only keys on the number pad that seem to work are `Enter` and `Back`. For other keys, I see escape like looking strings or I just hear a sound (which sounds like a keyboard buffer full type sound).

For example in Terminal when pressing `0` I see `^[[2~`, and when pressing `.` I hear the sound.  (As a comparison with the number pad connected to OSX, even though OSX says `Unknown keyboard` I still get the correct keystrokes out.  But on Windows 7 its different again and I only have workable  `+-/*` `<tab>` and `<enter>` keys)

Dumping out `dmesg` I get

```
[  233.313462] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ohci_hcd
[  233.525221] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=05a4, idProduct=9840
[  233.525221] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[  233.525221] usb 2-2: Product: USB Compliant Keypad
[  233.552503] input: USB Compliant Keypad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/input/input7
[  233.552669] generic-usb 0003:05A4:9840.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [USB Compliant Keypad] on usb-0000:00:06.0-2/input0
```

And for `lsusb -v` I get

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05a4:9840 Ortek Technology, Inc. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x05a4 Ortek Technology, Inc.
  idProduct          0x9840 
  bcdDevice            1.10
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                1 USB Compliant Keypad
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           34
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower               48mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.10
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      65
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              13
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

So it seems as if Debian has found the keyboard, but it hasn't wired it up as desired.

So what can I configure (no kernel compiling etc) to correctly enable this keyboard?  Or is it actually working correctly and I just don't know it?

**Edit**

I just plugged in a full sized USB keyboard into the system and everything worked straight away except for the numbers of the numeric keypad.  These behaved almost the same as above.  However, once I pressed `Numlock`, even the numeric kets worked.  So my guess is that the Number pad is working correctly, but that driver is not applying `Numlock` to the key codes coming from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Real **D'Oh** moment here

The problem **was** `Numlock`.

The solution was:

> System Settings -> Keyboard -> Layout settings -> Options ->
>   Miscellaneous compatibility options

I checked `Numeric keypad keys always enter digits (as in Mac OS)`

And now things work as I expected